# Why the value of the foreign key is always zero?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I try to build some application using hibernate for persistence (my first one). The application has genres and books. The genre class has a set of books. But every book in the set has the idGenre (the foreign key) value 0. I think the mapping is not right. Please tell me where is the mistake. Thanks.

Here is the mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping package = "model">

   <class name = "User" table="virtual_bookcase.users">
        <id name = "id" column = "id" type = "long">
            <generator class = "increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name = "username" column = "username" type = "string"/>
        <property name = "password" column = "password" type = "string"/>
   </class>

   <class name = "Genre" table = "virtual_bookcase.genres">
      <id name = "id" column = "idGenres" type = "long">
        <generator class = "increment"/>
      </id>   
      <property name = "name" column = "name" type = "string"/>
      <set name = "books" table = "virtual_bookcase.books" cascade = "all-delete-orphan">
        <key column = "idGenre" not-null = "true" />
        <one-to-many class = "Book"/>
      </set>
      <many-to-one name = "user" class = "User" column = "user_id" />
   </class>

   <class name = "Book" table = "virtual_bookcase.books">
        <id name = "id" column = "idBooks" type = "long">
         <generator class = "increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name = "title" column = "title" type = "string"/>
        <property name = "author" column = "author" type = "string"/>
        <property name = "publisher" column = "publisher" type = "string"/>
        <property name = "pages" column = "pages" type = "short"/>
        <property name = "borrowed" column = "borrowed" type = "byte"/>
        <property name = "borrowedTo" column = "borrowedTo" type = "string"/>
   </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is where i load the books:

```
Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();

Query q = s.createQuery("FROM Book WHERE idGenre = ?").setLong(0, g.getId());

books = new TreeSet<Book>(q.list());
```

Here is the Book class:

```
public class Book implements Comparable<Book>
{
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String publisher;
    private short pages;
    private byte borrowed;
    private String borrowedTo;
    private long idGenre;

public Book(){}
    public Book(String title, String author, String publisher, short pag, byte borrowed, String borrowedTo, long idGenre)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.pages = pag;
        this.borrowed = borrowed;
        this.borrowedTo = borrowedTo;
        this.idGenre = idGenre;
    }

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    public String getPublisher()
    {
        return publisher;
    }

    public short getPages()
    {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author)
    {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher)
    {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void setPages(short pages)
    {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public byte getBorrowed()
    {
        return borrowed;
    }

    public void setBorrowed(byte borrowed)
    {
        this.borrowed = borrowed;
    }

    public String getBorrowedTo()
    {
        return borrowedTo;
    }

    public void setBorrowedTo(String borrowedTo)
    {
        this.borrowedTo = borrowedTo;
    }

    public long getIdGenre()
    {
        return idGenre;
    }

    public void setIdGenre(long idGenre)
    {
        this.idGenre = idGenre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Book b)
    {
        if (this.title == b.getTitle() && this.author == b.getAuthor() && this.publisher == b.getPublisher() && this.pages == b.getPages())
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Here is how i make a new instance of a Book:

```
Book b = new Book("AddedBook", "A", "A", (short) 555, (byte) 0, "", 1);
Genre g = ((Genre) cmbGenres.getSelectedItem());
g.addBook(b);
control.saveGenre(g);
```

And the saveGenre(g) method is (without initialisation of SessionFactory and session and transaction):

```
   t = session.beginTransaction();
   Genre gr = (Genre) session.merge(g);
   t.commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Your mapping looks OK to me at first sight</strike>. My suspicion is that you may not properly associate your `Book` entities with the corresponding `Genre`. Could you post the code to create and persist `Book`s?

**Update:** your code looks like it could work, although it is not clear why you `merge` your genre (if you work with your entities in detached state during conversations spanning multiple sessions, it's OK, otherwise may be overcomplicating the picture). And the definition of `Genre.addBook` is missing, but I assume you did it right :-)

My new observation is that you haven't mapped `Book.idGenre`. Try extending your mapping like this:

```
<class name = "Book" table = "virtual_bookcase.books">
    ...
    <many-to-one name="idGenre" column="idGenre" class="Genre" not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

As a side note, this also makes some of the attributes on the other side of the association redundant - you could simplify it like this:

```
  <set name = "books" cascade = "all-delete-orphan">
    <key column = "idGenre"/>
    <one-to-many class = "Book"/>
  </set>
```

**Update2:** oops, and one more thing: replace `long idGenre` with a `Genre` property in `Book`, like

```
private Genre genre;
```

and of course update getter/setter, and mapping accordingly.

Comment: @DaJackal, this code only defines the `Book` class, and retrieves existing instances from the DB. How do you _create_ new instances of `Book`, and associate them to a `Genre`?

Comment: I made the updates, but now there are 2 exceptions: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of model.Book.idGenre and java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Comment: Thank you for your help, Peter. Now it seems that is working. But I think something is not right. In the Book entity, now I have a Genre field. But in the Genre entity, i have a set of Books, all the books the genre has. Now i'm learning hibernate, and I'm curious, there is no  other solution for mapping, in which the book entity has the idGenre field, not the Genre one?

Comment: @DaJackal, isn't it more natural to represent the association with a `Genre` property rather than a `long`? From the OO point of view, the id is just an implementation detail, which in fact would tie you to a persistence implementation using a relational DB. Hibernate avoids this dependency by relying directly on object properties instead of ids.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your patience and your explanations. Have a nice day!